# Pattern matching, matching multiple character

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

If I have a function that takes a string and say returns an int, I can match the first character of the string, using pattern matching:

```
f :: String -> Int
f ('A' : _) = 1
f ('B' : _) = 0
f ('C' : _) = 1
f _ = 2
```

is there a way to match A or C in one?
Something like:

```
f :: String -> Int
f ('A'||'C' : _) = 1
f ('B' : _) = 0
f _ = 2
```

or even this (which would be useful if there is some calculation rather than just returning a constant_)

```
f :: String -> Int
f ('A' : _)
f ('C' : _) = 1
f ('B' : _) = 0
f _ = 2
```

Answer (score 7):

Haskell does not have alternation in the pattern matching. You could solve the problem using  recursion:

```
f :: String -> Int
f ('A' : rest) = f ('C' : rest)
f ('B' : _) = 0
f ('C' : _) = 1
f _ = 2
```

You might consider using guards:

```
f ('B' : _) = 0
f (x : _) | x `elem` "AC" = 1
f _ = 2
```

Comment: in the latter example, you can just drop the otherwise

Answer (score 4):

Unfotunately you can't do this, a simple solution is

```
 f (x:_) | x == 'A' || x == 'C' = 1
         | x == 'B"             = 0
         | otherwise            = 2

 f ('B':_)  = 2
 f (x:_) | x == 'A' || x == 'C' = 1
 f _        = 0
```

This uses guards, but it's not terribly pattern match-y, it's really just like a chain of `if`s

I'd probably write this as

```
f ('A':_) = f "C"
f ('C':_) = 1
f ('B':_) = 0
f _       = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fake 'or-patterns' with a quasiquote that is attached at [ghc ticket 3919](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3919).

With the forthcoming (ghc-7.10?) [pattern synonyms](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms), you might be able to define a `pattern p1 :| p2 = ???` which does the same de-sugaring that the quasiquote in the previous link does.